# Can't complile when extendig abstract class

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I've got the next abstractions:

```
abstract class GraphUnit(var newsSources:Set<NewsSource>): NewsParent {
    //...
    fun getImportantNewsCompleted(): List<Informacion> {
        //Do something with the news sources...
    }

}
```

And implement it like this:

```
@Entity
class Scenario (
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "scenario")
    val tags: Set<Tag>
): GraphUnit(tags), NewsSource {
    //...
}

@Entity
class Tag (
   //...
):NewsSource{
    //...
}
```

But when I try to compile the program I get

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No noarg super constructor for CLASS
> CLASS name:Scenario modality:FINAL visibility:public
> superTypes:[com...kotlinbase.database.entity.interfaces.GraphUnit;
> com...kotlinbase.database.entity.interfaces.NewsSource]:
> CONSTRUCTOR visibility:public <>
> (newsSources:kotlin.collections.Set<com...kotlinbase.database.entity.interfaces.NewsSource>)
> returnType:com...kotlinbase.database.entity.interfaces.GraphUnit
> [primary]

However, it works this way, but it's less clean:

```
abstract class GraphUnit: NewsParent {
    //...
    abstract fun getNewsSources():Set<NewsSource>
    fun getImportantNewsCompleted(): List<Informacion> {
       val newsSources = getNewsSources()
       //...
    }

}

@Entity
class Escenario (
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "escenario")
    val etiquetas: Set<Etiqueta>
): GraphUnit(), NewsSource {
    override fun getNewsSources(): Set<NewsSource> {
        return etiquetas
    }
}
```

I've found this other SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73095777/no-noarg-super-constructor-for-class-class) talking about the same error but it seams that it's not the same issue as I'not even using no-arg plugin nor have used it before.